# <!DOCTYPE html> and older browsers

Tags: html, doctype, standards-compliance

Does `<!DOCTYPE html>` trigger standards mode for older browsers as well? Saying "in all modern browsers" isn't very precise.

I am especially interested in IE6.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you required to support IE6? If not: don't.

Comment: I am especially interested in IE6 because I am NOT required to support it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how the HTML5 doctype came into existance (in layman's terms):

The guys who make the standards wanted a simpler doctype. They found out that `<!DOCTYPE html>` (which is as simple as it gets) does trigger standards mode in browsers. They decided to standardize it in HTML5.

True story.

Comment: Thanks. I think the <meta charset/> one is even better, haha.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it does trigger (Almost) Standards Mode in older browsers (such as IE6).

See: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

> Standards mode, cutting edge
>   validation
>   `<!DOCTYPE html>`
>
> This is the right thing to do unless
>   you have a specific reason to avoid
>   it.

The only exception browser (according to that table) is NS6 which ***nobody*** is using.

Almost Standards Mode is almost identical to Standards Mode, with [some tiny, trivial exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko's_%22Almost_Standards%22_Mode):

> "Almost standards" rendering mode is
>   exactly the same as "standards" mode
>   in all details save one: the layout of
>   images inside table cells is handled
>   as they are in Gecko's "quirks" mode,
>   which is fairly consistent with other
>   browsers, such as Internet Explorer.