# html 5 doctype and older browsers

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm building a new website and I'm wondering what happens when an old broswer (IE7 for instance) requests a page and the doctype is HTML5? It's currently set as XHTML transitional but I'd like to add HTML5 videos. Should I switch to an HTML5 doctype?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<!DOCTYPE html> and older browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384625/doctype-html-and-older-browsers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML5 doctype was chosen as it is the bare minimum required to trigger web standards rendering mode in browsers that support it. It'll work fine in older browsers, but they won't support any of the HTML5 features or tags.

You can change the doctype right now if you want, but you won't get any new features.

In regard to the tags in HTML5, you can make old version of IE recognize and allow styling of the new tags with an [HTML5 Shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/). The [Modernizr script](http://www.modernizr.com/) also includes a Shim.

For HTML features like video and audio you'll need to use a technique called pollyfilling. These pollyfill libraries automatically fill in missing functionality for browsers that don't have it.

There are pollyfills around for most of the HTML5 features and for some of CSS3 too.

The Modernizr wiki has a [good list](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) of common pollyfills.

Many of these use the feature testing of Modernizr to determine if they need to do anything.

What happens for video is that the library checks for HTML5 availability, and falls back to flash if it is not available. Most replace the HTML5 native chrome with their own look and feel so that it looks the same regardless of which underlying code (native or flash) is being used.

For video [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) uses this approach and I would recommend that as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you'll have with HTML5 videos being inaccessible in older versions of IE is going to be the same regardless of the doctype. The standard practice, at least until HTML5 has wider support by browsers, is to use libraries that will gracefully fall back to Flash (or whatever your preferred fallback is) if the user's browser does not support HTML5. I've personally had success using JWPlayer for exactly this task.