# Link is not clickable in chrome and opera but in Firefox and IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, opera

I've a link tag around an image and it's working in IE and Firefox but it doesn't work in Chrome and Opera?

```
 <div class="gallery">
<a href="index.php?id=1331&no_cache=1&uid=1&mode=s"><img width="172" height="235" src="mi35.jpg"></a>
<div class="title">Mini</div>
</div>
```

I tried urlencode to no avail:

```
index.php%3Fid%3D1331%26no_cache%3D1%26uid%3D1%26mode%3Ds
```

I've removed no_cache=1 and urlencode in my php source code like this to no avail:

```
urlencode ( str_replace ( "no_cache=1", "", $this->pi_getPageLink ( $GLOBALS [ 'TSFE' ]->id, '',  array ( "uid" => $row [ "UID" ], "mode" => "s" ) )) );
```

Comment: Try `no%20cache` in the link instead.

Comment: I tried urlencode to no avail.

Comment: Show us your page, perhaps. Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/2BcJg/

Comment: I've removed no_cache=1 completley to no avail?

Comment: I've put all my html to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2BcJg/1/. It's seems someting else?

Comment: if by doesn't work you mean that the links default action is not working, then its *YOUR* browsers problem. This works in my browser. http://jsfiddle.net/2BcJg/1/show/ I am using Chrome.Please run the page in Chrome's incognito window disabling extensions and check. (Press CNTRL + SHIFT + n to go to incognito window mode)

Comment: What do you want to say?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In fact it was a problem in the CSS file and a negative z-index on the surroundig div of the image makes it impossible to click on the link.

Comment: please read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384625/doctype-html-and-older-browsers and whats the unholy `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` doiung there? please remove it... :)

Comment: I don't know. It's the latest T3 4.7 config. What is unholy <?xml version....? It's not a html standart?

Comment: Shrug. It's T3 config somewhere in TS. I don't want to remove it.

Comment: Haven't a clue what T3 or TS is but the `<?xml...` is an xml declaration for declaring an xml document and not to be used for HTML documents which this is. It is not "standard HTML". It also will send IE into quirks mode where no one ever wants to be. So remove that line.

Comment: Why should I? It's the default setting from T3?

Comment: BTW. This is my develop server. Maybe it's other in the wild? It's not my concern. I don't get paid to work for my a** off.