# Using background-image with DOCTYPE

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have a `.asp` page and I'm having problem showing the image when I place a `DOCTYPE` on top of the ASP page. If I delete the DOCTYPE on top then the image will show up. Can anyone please help me figure out how to show the image withour deleting the DOCTYPE on top? Please see coding below:

DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:200px"><span id="ImgHeader"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#ImgHeader
{
    background-image:url(img/header.jpg);
    width:200px;
    height:35px;
}
```

Comment: span is an inline element. you cannot set width and height of an inline element. change it to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: time to use modern DOCTYPE : `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Also, `<span>` is an inline element. Consider to set the background in `<td>` or change `<span>` to `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `<span>` is an inline element, you cannot apply `height` to it.

You should change `<span>` into `<div>`, which is a block element.

```
<td style="width:200px"><div id="ImgHeader"></div></td>
```

or apply the CSS selector to `<td>` if applicable:

```
<td id="ImgHeader">&nbsp;</td>
```

Last, it's time to change to a modern HTML5 DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Important: never remove the DOCTYPE.

p.s. if you are worried about old browser support of HTML5 DOCTYPE, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384641/188331). In short, old browser supports this DOCTYPE too (except NS6, which I believe nobody is using it)

Comment: I'll follow this one. Thank you for the advice.